# iOS 6 Transparent Tabbar possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am using storyboard in my app, in which i want to have transparent Tabbar in ios 6.

What i did is i have one tab bar image with some transparency in it when i add this code here,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     ...

     [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabImg.png"]];
     [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     ...
     ...
}
```

It shows Transperancy in iOS 7 but not in iOS 6.

is it possible to have Transparent tabbar background in iOS 6 ?

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Did you find solution?

Comment: Nope i am still searching :( the answer which is given works only for iOS 7 and not for iOS 6

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **tint color** property of **UITabBar**

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.5]];
```